# Implement command-ine arguments functionality using MVVM Light

Tags: localization, command-line-arguments

I need to implement localization using commandline arguments.

Comment: Farzi - please update this question with some more information/explanation. Cause as for today it is low quality one.

Comment: I have solved this issue of Mine.

Comment: can you post the solution as answer please? and accept it

Comment: Checked - much better )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for this

```
string[] cmd = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

What this will do is it will add all the arguments You pass through Cmd in an string Array and  then you can make use of those passed arguments for a particular functionality.

As In my case if I pass "eng" as command line argument the whole application will get tht "eng" culture.

So this is how I implemented Localization using CommandLineArguments.